# Is MVC Better at Managing Complexity When Working With Mostly JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I started making my project as a Website instead of a Web App. I am not sure whether or not I should switch to an application, and was hoping I could get some good references and feedback as to which design scheme I should implement to help me with my decision.

My confusion arises because I do not believe I will have much complexity in terms of server side code, but instead most of my complexity will be in JavaScript which will be partially built using inline code blocks. Is there any major benefit when working with complex, and lots of JavaScript to implement an MVC scheme, or is completely personal preference?

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what type of JavaScript application you're building, but I would say that MVC is definitely easier if you're building a single page application or an application that makes heave use of Ajax calls. MVC makes it much easier to request partial views and JSON than WebForms.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to mix MVC and Webforms in a single app (not ideal, but often for legacy reasons it is still necessary), see this article: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx

@TGH is correct that the ajax call handlers are easier to make in MVC, but whether that is relevant depends on the application you are making (i.e. will you be re-using those methods i multiple locations, etc.)

What the actual base page is (MVC vs. Webforms) is actually somewhat irrelevant. I have been using an .aspx base page (with no real server side code in it), and using ajax to make calls to MVC actions from it. The reason for this is so that I could still use the legacy master page we had in webforms (rather than duplicating the master page into an MVC layout page).

Depending on time/budget constraints, I would recommend you give MVC a go, to see if it would suit you. I did just that and found it to be great, but it might not be best for all (for example if you are very experienced with Webforms).

EDIT: One more thing I would add! You can make totally obscure and ridiculously complex applications in both MVC and Webforms. In other words, its not the technology that will save you ;). Design, test, re-iterate, always aiming for simplicity and clarity.